# Regular expression for allowing only SINGLE white space and single hyphen in between alpha numeric string

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, regex

I want a regular expression that prevents Special character and only allows letters and numbers and single white space and single hyphen. The regex below works great, but it doesn't allow for spaces between words.
^[A-Za-z-][A-Za-z0-9-]*$

string like:

```
test-test123 ---- Allowed 
test-123 ---- Allowed 
t12test-test123 ----Allowed
test test123 ---- Allowed 

test-           ---- Not Allowed
test--            ---- Not Allowed
test(withspace)           ---- Not Allowed


rest all special character are  not allowed
```

Comment: You mean `^[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*(?:[ -][A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*)*$`

Comment: It is always like this: `^{WORD}(?:{DELIMITER}{WORD})*$`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i need string like test-123(after hyphen or space it could be anything digit or later)

Comment: So, change the `[A-Za-z_]` to `[A-Za-z0-9]`